# ASP.Net Core Identity error after adding usernam "InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I added username to the identity and now I get this error when I try to register new user. The register goes trough the database but I get this error.

ERROR:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

in 
`OnPostAsync(string returnUrl)`

CODE:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]            
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email });
            }
            else
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: `register goes trough the database` You mean by this sentence that the user is being created in the database? And you can login with it or what?

Comment: Yes i can login and is saved but i get this error page.

Comment: Please share the code you are using to configure Identity services. And if you can share a reproducible sample, which would help troubleshoot the issue quickly.